# calling child class method from base class C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to call child class method from base class reference? Please suggest...

Code example is given below:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Child1:Parent
{
    public string Child1Property { get; set; }
}
public class Child2 : Parent
{
    public string Child2Property { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public void callMe()
    {
        Parent p1 = new Child1();
        Parent p2 = new Child2();

        //here p1 & p2 have access to only base class member.
        //Is it possible to call child class memeber from the base class reference based on the child class object it is referring to?
        //for example...is it possible to call as below:
        //p1.Child1Property = "hi";
        //p2.Child1Property = "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Only via reflection or by casting the base type to the child type first.

Comment: I am getting this issue while implementing factory method pattern. based on the condition, a child class is instantiated and assigned to the parent class reference. But it only refers to the parent members. So how do i make method call generic that will return appropriate child class object based on some condition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you´ve created a `Child1` and `Child2` instances, so you can *cast* to them:

```
  Parent p1 = new Child1();
  Parent p2 = new Child2();

  // or ((Child1) p1).Child1Property = "hi";
  (p1 as Child1).Child1Property = "hi";
  (p2 as Child2).Child2Property = "hello";
```

To check if *cast* successful, test for `null`:

```
  Child1 c1 = p1 as Child1;

  if (c1 != null)
    c1.Child1Property = "hi";
```

A better design, however, is assign to  `Child1` and `Child2` local variables

```
   Child1 p1 = Child1(); 
   p1.Child1Property = "hi";
```

Comment: then what is the benefit of creating a base class when at some point in code, we need to cast the parent object based on the same condition used in factory method?

Comment: @Tisha Anand: there's *no benefit* if you have to *cast*. But often we have no need to cast: all we may want, say, is a properly implemented `Property1` (which should be *virtual* or even *abstract* in this case) which is declared in the `Parent` class.

Comment: Thanks Dmirty :) So What I understand...if the child classes have a number of specific properties then besides declaring these properties as virtual or abstract in parent class, we can use cast operator to set child class individual properties. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @Tisha Anand: you're right, in case of few specific properties you can use cast; but too many casts make the code *unreadable* and in that case (child classes are *too different* from one another) you, probably, have to restrain from factory methods.